# How to display data in div tag using data-src

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, entity-framework

the code using to show image .

HTML:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Rep_slider" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div data-src='<%#("~/PicUpload/") + Eval("pic")%> '  runat="server">
            <div class="camera_caption moveFromLeft camera_text_center">
                <div class="caption_slider h2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

The code using to select from DB:

```
 var slideshow = from anything in obj.sliders
                    select anything;
    Rep_slider.DataSource = slideshow.ToArray();
    Rep_slider.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want display div with background image. Try use `style="background-image:url('<%#("~/PicUpload/") + Eval("pic")%>')"` instead data-src